# Inconsistent behavior in JavaScript's conditional checking

Tags: javascript

I want to build an object `obj1` with property `obj2`, which is another object.  To avoid redeclaring `obj1` and `obj2`, I use the following code:

```
if (!obj1) obj1 = {};
if (!obj1.obj2) obj1.obj2 = {};
// code to use obj1
```

Assume, `obj1` and `obj1.obj2` aren't defined yet, the code causes the browser to report the error "obj1 is not defined".

If I change the code to:

```
if (typeof obj1==='undefined') obj1 = {};
if (!obj1.obj2) obj1.obj2 = {};
// code to use obj1
```

Then there's no error, while I think it should report "obj2 is not defined".  I'm puzzled as to why the JavaScript treats the short-hand falsy check of a reference and a property differently.  Can anyone shed a light on that?

Comment: You can do `if(!window.obj1)`.

Comment: `obj1` is a type, `obj2` is a property.

Comment: offtopic: it's not that nice, it's a simple "scope of variables" question; ontopic: a variable cannot be checked for value(first sample) before it is declared, second code sample checks for existence, and as a best practice do declare your variables you are using do not let the interpreter to make the declarations for you, you can declare your "global" variables at the beginning of the js file and after that use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would do:

```
if (!window.obj1) window.obj1 = {};
if (!obj1.obj2) obj1.obj2 = {};
```

You will find the code works as you expect.

`obj1` isn't even a reference when you check it's existance; it's nothing. It doesn't exist because you haven't declared it (neither have you initialized it).

```
var obj1;

if (!obj1) obj1 = {};
if (!obj1.obj2) obj1.obj2 = {};
```

This will also work because you've declared the existance of `obj1`; you just haven't initialized it.

All properties of an object that haven't been set hold the value `undefined`; which is why it responds to your short hand `!obj1.obj2`

```
var obj1 = {};
obj1.a === undefined // true;
```

Variables however, must be defined before you can access them.

Comment: @TimDown: Thanks, didn't realise that. Assuming the updated answer will?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Implicit global variables throw errors in ES5 strict, but assigning a property to the global object is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think the latter code boils down to §8.7.1 and §8.12.3 in [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

8.7.1 GetValue

> 1. If Type(V) is not Reference, return V.
> 2. Let base be the result of calling GetBase(V). If
> 3. IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a
>      ReferenceError exception.
> 4. If
>      IsPropertyReference(V), then
>
> > a. If
> >     HasPrimitiveBase(V) is false, then let
> >     get be the [[Get]] internal method of
> >     base, otherwise let get be the special
> >     [[Get]] internal method defined below.
> >
> > b. Return the result of calling the
> >     get internal method using base as its
> >     this value, and passing
> >     GetReferencedName(V) for the argument.
>
> 5. Else, base must be an environment
>   record.
>
> > a. Return the result of
> >     calling the GetBindingValue (see
> >     10.2.1) concrete method of base passing GetReferencedName(V) and
> >     IsStrictReference(V) as arguments.

8.12.3 [[Get]]

> When the [[Get]] internal method of O
>   is called with property name P, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 8. Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of
>   O with property name P.
>
> 9. If desc is
>   undefined, return undefined.
>
> 10 If
>   IsDataDescriptor(desc) is true, return
>   desc.[[Value]].
>
> 11 Otherwise,
>   IsAccessorDescriptor(desc) must be
>   true so, let getter be desc.[[Get]].
>
> 12. If getter is undefined, return
>   undefined.
>
> 13. Return the result calling
>   the [[Call]] internal method of getter
>   providing O as the this value and
>   providing no arguments.

As you can see, it only throws a `ReferenceError` here for `IsUnresolvableReference`.  That applies if the base (obj1) is undefined.  There is a list of places where ReferenceError is thrown in §15.11.6.3.

Answer (score 3):

The "obj1" reference is not declared at all, as a result you get an error.

Use the following syntax for such kind of check:

```
var obj1 = obj1 || {};
```

By the way:

```
if (typeof obj1==='undefined') obj1 = {};
```

does not help if obj1 == null.

Don't declare global variables (without var). 
And I strongly recommend you to read the JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 5th Edition.
You may skip some chapters but pay your attention to Chapters 3, 7, 8, 9. They must be read and understood.

Comment: +1 for addressing the real problem: the need to understand better how to program using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reconstruct it using chrome JScript console

If you add a watch expression to both obj1 and obj1.obj2 before your two lines both are of course not defined:

`obj1: ReferenceError: obj1 is not defined`

obj1.obj2: ReferenceError: obj1 is not defined

As soon as you go over this line  `if (typeof obj1==='undefined') obj1 = {};` all of a sudden they turn into

`obj1: Object`

obj1.obj2: undefined

So, you cannot check the first with `!` because it is not `undefined`

Hope this helps

Comment: Google Chrome's JS-debugger; It could be obtained also with Firebug